# Weak-* compactness of probability measures on compact, non-Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a compact topological space.  How would I prove that the space of probability measures $\Delta(X)$ is weak-* compact?  Without assuming $X$ being Hausdorff I can't apply to the usual Reisz representation type arguments, which are currently the only real tool in my toolkit for uncountable $X$.

This is a 'for the love of the game' type question rather than something for specific application/study, but if anyone could show how I'd want to approach such a problem, I'd be very interested.

Comment: So you are treating these measures as a subset of $C(X)^{\ast}$ (the dual of $C(X)$) correct? If so, you only need to prove it is weak-$\ast$ closed in the unit ball of $C(X)^{\ast}$ and apply Banach-Alaoglu.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I think that's the crux of my uncertainty: normally that first step would be no problem in the Hausdorff case because of the Reisz representation theorem, but here am I allowed to just do that out of hand?

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks, that's a really interesting idea.  So you're saying let's take the maximal Hausdorff quotient of $X$, $Y$ (which is compact).  For all functions $\bar{f}\in C(Y, \mathbb{R})$ I believe I should have a unique $f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$.  So by the usual arguments I get $\Delta(Y)$ compact.  But I'm not sure now how to pull that argument back to $X$ to say something useful?

Comment: @Doug Good point. It's been a while, so I don't know if I had anything in mind how to go back from $Y$ to $X$. But probably this comment was just naive. I deleted it now.